# Disable site content anonymous user and throw exception

Tags: anonymous-authentication, site-contents

I had a request from client side. 
They want disable access to http://mysite/_layouts/viewlsts.aspx from anonymous user, no login and throw an exception : The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred
Anyone could help me for archive this. Thank you guys

Comment: Your question is slightly difficult to understand, can you please rephrase it.

Comment: when end user access to site content, there is no login form and throw an error message : The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.
Prevent our client access or hack to site content. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Restricting user from accessing layouts path

Add below entries in web.config file of the site you want to restrict.

```
<location path="_layouts/15/viewlsts.aspx">
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <allow users="domain\UserLoginName" />
    <deny users="?" />
    <deny users="*" />
  </authorization>
</system.web>
</location>
```